# Problems with installing aircrack-ng on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, aircrack-ng

I have found a tutorial on how to install `aircrack-ng` on Ubuntu 12.04 because it's not in the repositories anymore. I followed these instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev

wget http://download.aircrack-ng.org/aircrack-ng-1.1.tar.gz
tar -xzvf aircrack-ng-1.1.tar.gz
cd aircrack-ng-1.1
nano common.mak
```

I found this: `CFLAGS          ?= -g -W -Wall -Werror -O3`

and removed it with this: `CFLAGS          ?= -g -W -Wall -O3`

After that I scrolled to the bottom and typed `make` and nothing happened . I tried `sudo make install` but nothing happened as well.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

There is a ppa for that and it works all the way up to 13.04. It also contains reaver if you want it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:pi-rho/security
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y aircrack-ng
```